# Extract two equally sized objects from a list

Tags: java-8, extract

```
private static final List<List<L2PcInstance>> LOBBY = new LinkedList<>();
```

How can I extract two equally sized lists out of list LOBBY using Java 8? I prefer a one-line way or so.

More precisely, I want every 10 second to select a pair of equally sized lists from `LOBBY`. So if `LOBBY` contains let's say three lists (1st list = 3 elements, 2nd list = 2 elements, 3rd list = 2 elements), it shall make a pair of lists 2 and 3 and remove them from `LOBBY`.

Comment: Well, there's `List.size()` and `List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`.

Comment: Yes but the point is to extract 2 similar object which in this case is 2 lists with same size.

Comment: I'd advise to tackle `every 10 second` as a separate problem - and question. Will `LOBBY` stay unmodified between extractions?

Comment: I already made the 10 second, i just mention to get the idea that is a lobby and every 10 seconds it find 2 pair of same sized lists and extract them ( remove to do something else ). So basically every 10 second i want pick 2 equally sized list and remove em (and obviously do something with the content of them)

Answer (score 0):

*Java 8* may have been a hint:
Map the elements of `LOBBY` to int, turn into array, sort.
Pick a length occurring more than once,
extract two elements with this length.